# In ASM 9.2 as argument of Inner class constructor, how to differentiate outer class argument (added by compiler) vs written in code?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

To access the outer class, if the inner class contains constructors without the outer class reference as an argument, the compiler can add the outer class reference as an argument. In **ASM 9.2** byte code decompiler, is there any way to know whether that argument was added by the compiler or it was written in the code already?

Comment: Do you want to know whether the *constructor* was written explicitly or whether the *parameter* was written explicitly?

Comment: @Holger I was trying to differentiate from the byte code whether the parameter was written in the code or added later by the compiler. As far as I know, for all the constructors of the inner class, the compiler will add the reference of outer class if not explicitly added in the code.

Comment: The phrase “if the inner class does not contain any constructor …” is very misleading. If a constructor does not contain an explicit declaration for the outer this parameter, it doesn’t matter whether the class contains “any” constructor that has one. *All* constructors have to have such a parameter, hence, it is entirely irrelevant what the other constructors of the inner class have. The implicit parameter is added in any case. Anyway, the ability to declare it explicitly only exists since Java 8 and is rarely used at all. Would it really matter to your program logic if it exists?

Comment: @holger, yeah. I should have phrased it better. I am trying to find source code from byte code. So in that case, it's not possible to differentiate whether the outer class reference was added by the compiler or originally written by the coder and probably it's not possible to do that.

Comment: Do you mean decompiling? Just assume the outer reference to be implicit, unless it has annotations.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is no way. Newer javac versions add the MANDATED modifier to generated parameters for which you can check. Also, the constructor itself can be marked SYNTHETIC.